# C++ class scope

Tags: c++, class

I'm coming to C++ from Objective C and have a problem...
This works :-

```
function1(char *filePath) {

    Box box(filePath); // construct/create a box using filePath

    // can use box in this function and destructor is called when function exits

}
```

However I need something like this, where function1 and function2 are called asynchronously.

```
Box *boxPool[25]; // a pool of 25 box pointers

function1(int item, char *filePath) {

    boxPool[item](filePath); // construct/create a box, store a pointer in boxPool that is retained on exit

}

function2(int item) {

    // use the box from boxPool[item] and then destruct/release it on exit

}
```

Comment: I missed the square brackets out of the second function1.

Box *boxPool[25]; // a pool of 25 box pointers

function1(int item, char *filePath) {

boxPool[item]; // construct/create a box, store a pointer in boxPool that is retained on exit

}

Comment: Will function1 and function2 be called from different threads?

Comment: I would change the title of this question.  It is not really about class scope.  It is more about dynamic allocation of objects in C++ and the operator new.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe:

```
void function1(int item, char *filePath) {

    boxPool[item] = new Box(filePath);

}

void function2(int item) {

  //use boxPool[item]

  delete boxPool[item];
  boxPool[item] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: short, concise, and accurate. Better than what I was going to post! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Box *boxPool[25];
```

boxPool is an array of 25 pointers to Box objects.

```
Box boxPool[25];
```

Is an array of 25 Box objects.

Comment: Box* boxPool is an array of 25 Box pointers, not objects, isn't it?